# Python encoding issue with pandas read_sql

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

So I am trying to encode two strings to utf-8 so I can use them with pandas.read_sql:

```
selectedTable = "ACC__AccountCodes"
baseSql = "SELECT * FROM FileMaker_Fields WHERE TableName="
```

Now when I encode these two things:

```
baseSql.encode('utf-8')
selectedTable.encode('utf-8')
sqlString = "{}{}".format(baseSql, selectedTable)
```

My output looks like this:

`b'SELECT * FROM FileMaker_Fields WHERE TableName='b'A\x00C\x00C\x00_\x00_\x00A\x00c\x00c\x00o\x00u\x00n\x00t\x00C\x00o\x00d\x00e\x00s\x00''`

So when I run it with encoding set to 'latin1' I get the error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM FileMaker_Fields WHERE TableName=ACC__AccountCodes': ('HY000', '[HY000] [\x00F\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00M\x00a\x00k\x00e\x00r\x00]\x00[\x00F\x00i\x00l\x00e\x00M\x00a\x00k\x00e\x00r\x00]\x00 \x00F\x00Q\x00L\x000\x000\x000\x007\x00/\x00(\x001\x00:\x004\x007\x00)\x00:\x00 \x00T\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00c\x00o\x00l\x00u\x00m\x00n\x00 \x00n\x00a\x00m\x00e\x00d\x00 \x00"\x00A\x00"\x00 \x00d\x00o\x00e\x00s\x00 \x00n\x00o\x00t\x00 \x00e\x00x\x00i\x00s\x00t\x00.....
```

I can't seem to find anything addressing this. Everything I have tried leads me back to this which causes a sql error for invalid syntax. I am using pyodbc which expects utf-8 encoding as the input. Thoughts?

Comment: You shouldn't need explicit encoding. I recently set up pyodbc with FileMaker ODBC on Windows and the default Unicode encoding for pyodbc (which is UTF-16LE, BTW) worked fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks I will give it another shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to encode them as utf-8; Try passing them as normal strings to pandas `read_sql` function, it should work fine, if not, then you have a problem somewhere else... but encoding is not what you want here.

`Pyodbc` accepts unicode strings in the query as normal, so that is not your problem at all.

I suggest also reading the [**Unicode section on pyodbc documentation**](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode) that contains specific unicode configuration for some databases, although in your case I don't see that being a problem at all, because it is related to the database driver encoding and not your sql query, which should be a normal unicode string every time.

Comment: Edited my question. I am using pyodbc which expects utf-8 encoding as the input.

Comment: @L.Norman Your assumptions are wrong. I'm also using `pyodbc` and it works fine with normal unicode strings here. Show your code and the error you get when you use normal unicode strings, instead.

Comment: Why are you setting the encoding in first place?

Comment: I believe my database output has utf characters in it. Edited my post